# Convert (text) rows into Columns in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014, dynamic-pivot

I'm trying to capture rows for a specific group and then convert them into columns naming the script's headers.

This is an example of data:

```
FORMULAS  | INSTRUCTIONS
----------+----------------------------------------------------
AF100120  | **ACETALDEHYDE WARNING - USE APPROPRIATE CAUTION**
AF100120  | ADD REMAINING ITEMS   
AF100120  | DISSOLVE ITEMS 1-2 IN 3 
AF100120  | IF HEAT USED, COOL TO ROOM TEMPERATURE 
AF100120  | MIX UNTIL HOMOGENEOUS                                                                               
AF100120  | MIXING TIMES VARY WITH BATCH SIZE                                                                   
AF100997  | 1) DISSOLVE THYMOL CRYSTALS IN ETHYL ALCOHOL. MIX WELL.
AF100997  | 2) ADD REMAINING ITEMS AND MIX UNTIL UNIFORM.
AF100997  | 3) FILTER IF NOT CLEAR
```

The desired output for this script is:

```
FORMULAS | INSTRUCTION #1 |INSTRUCTION #2 | INSTRUCTION #3 |INSTRUCTION #4 |INSTRUCTION #5|INSTRUCTION #6

AF100120 |**ACETALDEHYDE..| ADD REMAINING.| DISSOLVE ITEM. |IF HEAT USED.. |MIX UNTIL H   |MIXING TIM...
AF100997 |1) DISSOLVE THYM| 2) ADD REMAINI| FILTER IF NOT  | NULL          |NULL          |NULL
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         A.FormulaId AS FORMULAS, 
         CAST(B.Instruction AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [INSTRUCTIONS]
     FROM 
         Formulas AS A
     LEFT JOIN 
         FormulaProcedures AS B ON A.FormulaId = B.FormulaId
     WHERE 
         B.ProcedureType = 3 
         AND PhaseType = 2 
         AND YEAR(A.VersionDate) >= '2018' 
         AND A.PrimaryVersion = 1 
         AND A.FormulaId IN('AF100120', 'AF100997')
     GROUP BY  
         A.FormulaId, CAST(B.Instruction AS NVARCHAR(100))
    ) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT
    (MAX([INSTRUCTIONS]) 
         FOR [INSTRUCTIONS] IN ([INSTRUCTION #1], [INSTRUCTION #2],
                                [INSTRUCTION #3], [INSTRUCTION #4],
                                [INSTRUCTION #5], [INSTRUCTION #6])) AS PivotTable;
```

Thank you!

Comment: what tells us order?  for example your formula of "AF100120", how do we know the order of the instructions? That will be a key piece to the solution.

Comment: is there any sort of order column in the FormulaProcedures table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use Dynamic Pivot including `ROW_NUMBER()` function with values grouped by `formulas` ordered by `instructions` column in order to number the column names along with iteration of that analytic function :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('formulas',[rn])) AS formulas
                FROM 
                (
                 SELECT f.*, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                 (PARTITION BY [formulas] ORDER BY [instructions]) AS rn
                   FROM [Formulas_Tab] f
                ) ff
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET  @query = 
 N'SELECT *  
     FROM
     (
       SELECT f.*, 
              CONCAT(''formulas'',
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                              (PARTITION BY [formulas] ORDER BY [instructions])) AS rn
         FROM [Formulas_Tab] f
      ) ff
    PIVOT 
    (
     MAX([instructions]) FOR [rn] IN (' + @cols + N')
    ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=340b430659b3f983d9c6e3f84fcc674d)</kbd>

If your version of installed database was **2017+**, then you'd use `STRING_AGG()` function in order to determine `@cols` variable as

```
SELECT @cols =
SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT('formulas', [ rn ])), ',') AS formulas
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
          ( PARTITION BY [ formulas ] ORDER BY [ instructions ]) AS rn
     FROM [ Formulas_Tab ] f
  ) ff
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Barbados, that works. I could add more columns and used for thousands of records

Comment: you're welcome @GabrielMolina , sure you can as being dynamic. Btw, NVARCHAR(MAX) holds 2GB ( upto 536.870.912 chars)